# How can I find the memory address of an object property in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory

I am looking for the location in memory in a game(Celeste) for the current room location, to create static pointers to it. Although in code this value is a string, it is not stored as a string in memory. My next step was to create a mod for this game to log the address in memory of this object during runtime.

Originally, I used the GCHandle class

```
private void Level_OnLoadLevel(Level level, Player.IntroTypes playerIntro, bool isFromLoader)
{
    unsafe
    {
        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(level.Session.LevelData.Name, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        string pointer = ((Int64)GCHandle.ToIntPtr(handle)).ToString();
        Logger.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "AddressLogger", $"{pointer}");
    }
}
```

I thought this would provide a 9 digit integer in hex, that would point to the address where the Name property is stored. Instead, I was getting improbably low numbers(like 10, 43, 252), the value of which would change between rooms, which was also unexpected.

Next, I tried this:

```
private void Level_OnLoadLevel(Level level, Player.IntroTypes playerIntro, bool isFromLoader)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed(string* pointer = &level.Session.LevelData.Name)
        {
            Logger.Log(LogLevel.Verbose, "AddressLogger", $"address = {(Int64)pointer}");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I was getting valid addresses in memory, but the behaviors of the values was incorrect, and would vary between sessions. Sometimes the value was static, and would not change when the current room was changed, sometimes it would change many times within the same room.

I then asked Chat GPT4 a similar question, and it said that in c# it was impossible to get a pointer to a property of an object, even if that object was pinned in memory. Is that true, or is there some way to get the address?

Comment: It is indeed impossible to get a pointer to a *property*, as that's just a set of methods, but you *can* get a pointer to a field. However, presumably what you're actually looking for is the offset of the field inside the object rather than any kind of absolute address, as that address becomes instantly unusable once the object is no longer pinned -- the whole reason for pinning it is so the garbage collector doesn't move or invalidate it. Compounding this is that strings in C# are immutable -- all that changes is the value assigned to `Name`. A "static pointer" to this value is not possible.

Comment: 1. Strings are immutable in C#. If "the room name changes", the property points to a *different* string. Thus, getting the address of the (old) string won't help you. 2. Your pointer is only fixed as long as the code is inside the `fixed` block. Thus, `(Int64)pointer` returning a different value when `OnLoadLevel` is executed again is not unexpected.

Comment: `GCHandle`'s "value" is an index into a table, not the address.  You can use a GCHandle to pin a particular object long-term, which means that the pointer value each time you view it (using a `fixed` block) will remain in place.  But if you have a reference to the object in order to pin it, why don't you just save that reference?  Then you're working in concert with the garbage collector instead of fighting against it.

Comment: @Heinzi I believe he's not trying to get the address of the string content, but the field of `string` type that refers to the string

Comment: Finally, you seem to be looking inside different `Level` objects each time.  Naturally the address of members will be different when looking at different objects.